# JAVA | Resultado de 7 + 1 + "4 + 2" + 1 + 7

Tags: java

¿Cuánto es el resultado de la siguiente operación en JAVA?
7 + 1 + "4 + 2" + 1 + 7

Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Cual es la duda? Y si puedes agregar un código de ejemplo, mejor.

Comment: Hola Julian, trata de agregar siempre lo que has intentado o investigado, saludos!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Cuando se usa el simbolo "+" con un String, lo que hace es una concatenación.

Una vez un String a sido concatenado, todo lo siguiente es tratado como String por lo que es añadido sin ejecutarse la suma.

Debido a ello sólo el primer "+" es considerado como la operación suma, mientras que el tercer + es considerado concatenación.

```js
console.log(7 + 1 + "4 + 2" + 1 + 7)
```

Si quisieras seguir sumando despues de haber concatenado un String, puedes usar un "(" para que el compilador ejecute la suma.

```js
 console.log(7 + 1 + "4 + 2" + (1 + 7))
```

Comment: Por favor ayúdanos a responder preguntas que se encuentren realizadas en base a lo dictado en [ask] , hay que sugerir mejorar las preguntas y evitar agregar preguntas de "baja calidad" en el sitio, saludos.

Comment: Solo considera que el OP pregunto usando como lenguaje Java y no JavaScript